# Defining a topocentric CRS with custom orientation in WKT

Tags: coordinate-system, gdal, well-known-text

I have a dataset collected by a drone that I need to transform into an existing topocentric coordinate system with custom orientation.
The data is given in UTM coordinates, and the local coordinate system is defined in terms of two coordinates measured with GPS (one is origin, the second defines the orientation of the X-axis).

I have a working transformation, which I have described mathematically (WGS84 -> ECEF -> ENU topocentric -(Z-axis rotation)-> Custom topocentric). I have implemented and tested that it works through some code I wrote, but I want to be able to take advantage of the features software like QGIS and GDAL provide. I was also able to write the transformation as a PROJ pipeline, but that is not recognized as a valid CRS.

```
+proj=pipeline +step +proj=cart +ellps=WGS84 +step +proj=topocentric +ellps=WGS84 +lon_0=-114.96 +lat_0=36.07 +h_0=448.81 +step +proj=affine +s11=-0.67969 +s12=0.73349 +s13=0.0 +s21=-0.73349 +s22=-0.67969 +s23=0.0 +s31=0.0 +s32=0.0 +s33=1.0
```

What I would like, is to describe it using WKT, such that GDAL and the likes will recognize it and allow transformations to and from other CRSs. I have tried, but I find the WKT standard document difficult to parse, and I haven't found any guides or questions here on GIS Stackexchange that really could provide a useful answer, so I'm hoping you can help me here.